# Getting ffmpeg error “Error initializing complex filters”

Tags: ffmpeg, java, video-encoding

I'm using ffmpeg in my java program.
Here is my command, it works fine on the terminal and Windows application, but when it runs on the Mac application, it keeps giving me this error **Error initializing complex filters**.

```
ffmpeg -y -framerate 30 -start_number 0 -i /Users/Images/image_m01_%03d.png -ss 0.0 -t 3.33 -i /Users/Sounds/info_01.wav -ss 0.0 -t 3.5 -i /Users/Sounds/info_02.wav -filter_complex "[1] aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a1]; [a1]adelay=0.0|0.0,apad[b1]; [2] aformat=sample_fmts=s16p:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo [a2]; [a2]adelay=0.0|0.0[b2]; [b1][b2]amerge=2[a]" -map 0:v -map [a] -b:v 2800k -c:v libopenh264 -c:a mp3 -ac 2 /Users/Movies/video.mp4
```

I've tried using **'** instead of **"**, but still got same error.

Comment: Can you please show the entire command-line output? The `|` pipe does not need additional escaping if it's between quotes. Perhaps you have to quote the final `-map "[a2]"`

Comment: @slhck Error occurred on my java program, errorStream didn't give me any further informations.

Comment: @slhck Do you mean `|` in `[a1]adelay=0.0|0.0,apad[b1]`? Looks like it is necessary to separate delay and apad.

Comment: ffmpeg prints quite a bit of output to STDERR, not just “error initializing complex filters”. Please show the entire output of that.